# Wireless keeps disconnecting Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: wireless

This starts to occur after upgrading to Ubuntu 14.04. The only way to solve it is to un-tick "Enable Networking" then enable it again. This works only for a while.
I'd appreciate any help. 
Thanks

Comment: Are there any proprietary network drivers available under `System Settings`->`Software&Updates`->`Additional drivers`?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I see this :"No additional drivers available" and also " No proprietary drivers in use" ?